# Is it possible to run a thread, that executes a function in a loop, only when a condition is met, which is also checked in a loop?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

I want to check in one `thread A` if a condition is met,
if the condition is `true` I want another `thread B` to execute my code, once that is done, I want `thread B` to wait until that condition is true again, then it executes the code again, and so on. There is enough time to execute all the code in `thread B` before the condition is `false`. Basically `thread A` runs at normal speed, `thread B` only runs when `thread A` tells it it can run. And I don't want to spawn a new `thread B` all the time, it shouldn't stop, it should just execute it's code and then wait until it's allowed to execute it's code again.

How can I do that? Below is what I have so far, but I don't how to run `mainExecution()` in this type of loop?

```
std::mutex m;
std::condition_variable cv_can_execute;

bool b_can_execute = false;


void mainExection() {
    std::unique_lock lk(m);
    cv_can_execute.wait(lk, [] { return b_can_execute; });

    doSomethingElse();
    
}

void canExecute() {
    std::unique_lock lk(m); 


    while (true) {
        condition = canRun();

        if (condition) {
            b_can_execute = true;
            cv_can_execute.notify_all();
        }
        else {
            b_can_execute = false;
        }

    }

   
    b_add_done = true;
    cv_add_done.notify_all();
}

int main() { 
    

    std::thread canExec(canExecute);
    std::thread mainExec(mainExection);
   
    canExec.join();
    mainExec.join();
  
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you see? What works already? There are obvious errors in the code, (consider [mcve]), so it's hard to guess what stops you. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: and also please use the same `thread` names in your question that match the `thread`  names in the code snippet for readers to help you solve the given problem. For example, we don't see any `thread A` and `thread B`  in the code snippet?

Answer (score 1):

In your code both threads immediately lock mutex `m`, so only one can run at a time.
That's why you don't see the behavior you expect.

You should only lock the mutex when you want to touch shared memory,in your case `b_can_execute`. The code should look something like this:

```
void mainExection() {
    {
      std::unique_lock lk(m);
      cv_can_execute.wait(lk, [] { return b_can_execute; });
    }  // Here the lock is released so A can do work.
  
    doSomethingElse();
}
void canExecute() {
    // std::unique_lock lk(m);  Remove this
    while (true) {
        condition = canRun();

        if (condition) {
            {
              std::unique_lock lk(m);  // Lock to change shred variable.
              b_can_execute = true;
            }  // Unlock here, so B can run
            // It's best to unlock before you notify, so that B doesn't wake just to block again.
            cv_can_execute.notify_all();
        }
        else {
            std::unique_lock lk(m);
            b_can_execute = false;
        }

    }

    {
      std::unique_lock lk(m);
      b_add_done = true;
    }
    cv_add_done.notify_all();
}
```

Now, in your case you only lock the mutex to synchronize on a bool. This is usually seen as overkill as the cost of lock and unlocking is relatively high. You could try to look at atomic variables which would replace your bool and allow the threads to synchronize without the use of the mutex.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have made it work before seeing your answer.       `void threadA() {

 while (!breakcondition)) {
 
  std::unique_lock lk(m);
  cv_can_execut.wait(lk);
  // do stuff here
 }

}
int main() {

 std::thread thrA(threadA);
 thrA.detach();


 while (!breakcondition) {

  condition = canRun();

  if (condition) {

   b_can_execute = true;
   cv_can_execute.notify_all();
  }
  else {
   b_can_execute = false;
  }

 }
 return 0;
}`           I will try yours. I tried atomic bool but the thread was not syncing. It ran too fast.

Comment: @Hyperh If I read your code correctly threadA will hold the lock while `// do suff here` is running. This is something to avoid unless you need that code to run exclusively. In general you want to hold the locks for the least amount of time.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand that correctly. That code won't run exclusively, since the thread is detached and my main thread is not waiting for it to finish.  Basically the main thread runs all the time, let's say 5000 times per second, and it checks if threadA is allowed to run. ThreadA is supposed to run for example 60 times a second, so it needs to wait until the condition is true. I have to lock it in a loop to check the condition. What would be a better way?

Comment: @Hyperh I'm talking about the actual work you want to do,... `// do stuff here` . If you are holding the lock while that code runs, it means that your main thread will have to wait for the lock to set the bool again.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want to happen. I named the functions poorly here. CanExecute() is the thread, that runs all the time and mainExecution() only runs when the bool is set, if it's not it waits. The solution I posted is working perfectly fine, just wondering if there is something I could do better there and also there will 3 additional threads running that work just like mainExecution. I'm not sure if I can use the same cond. variable, so I will use 3 additional ones that will be set in CanExecute().